# eth0 invisible (Dell latitude E5470, Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

Shortly after purchasing my computer (new, with Ubuntu installed by Dell), I updated it. The problem is that all my internet interfaces are gone...
eth0 is not showing in ifconfig and /etc/network/interfaces only has :

```
#interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

what should I do ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help. /sys/class/net only contains a lo/ directory...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the connection is recognized using 
`ip link` If you see the device use `ip link set <device name> up` and it should be available using ifconfig.

If you don't see the device it's a driver issue.